# instantiate class method issue while trying to resize and image

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

I am quite new to iOS development and its my first time trying to resize and image and dealing with class methods.

I am following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282830/uiimagepickercontroller-uiimage-memory-and-more?rq=1) post on how to resize an image. I placed the `+ (UIImage*)imageWithImage:(UIImage*)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize;` in `selectExerciseImageViewController.h` and copied the relevant code to `selectExerciseImageViewController.m`.

Then trying to instantiate the class using

```
    selectExerciseImageViewController * newC = [[selectExerciseImageViewController alloc] init];
  UIImage* newImage = [newC imageWithImage:[info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"]
      scaledToSizeWithSameAspectRatio:CGSizeMake(40.0,40.0)];
```

but its throwing an error saying that there is not visible interface for that method. i tried putting `self` instead of `newC` but still throws the same error.

I would appreciate some guidance on why its behaving like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your

```
+ (UIImage*)imageWithImage:(UIImage*)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize;
```

method is a class method and you are trying to invoke it on an instance of selectExerciseImageViewController. Try:

```
[selectExerciseImageViewController imageWithImage:[info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"]
  scaledToSizeWithSameAspectRatio:CGSizeMake(40.0,40.0)];
```

or you can declare your method as an instance method, just change the + sign (class method) to a - sign (instance method)

```
- (UIImage*)imageWithImage:(UIImage*)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize;
```